# CSS to make border stop inside float-induced padding

Tags: css, css-float, border, padding

Is there any CSS that can ***dynamically*** make a border stop at the edge of content next to a float, rather than continuing under the float? Yes, I know similar questions have been asked, but the only answers I've found were to add a hard-coded custom margin with the exact number of pixels of the specific float+padding. This is a responsive layout and involves images of various sizes, so I'm hoping there is CSS I can apply as a class to all headings that don't clear floats (or to all images expected to end up beside them).

The page I'm currently fighting with is https://japan.deafmin.org/work, but in case that page changes later, here is a screenshot - I want the green "underline" (actually `border-bottom` on the `<h3>`) to line up with the text rather than extending to the photos.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div.entry-content h3 {
    color: #67c18c;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! All I had to add was the `display:flex` - everything else was already defined. I guess the reason why this solution was not mentioned on other threads I could find is because they were from several years ago - flexbox is pretty new. Thanks!

Comment: And I might add that using flex this way (without any boxes inside it) is pretty counter-intuitive - it would have never occurred to me. But it works great.